# Suggestions for speeding up double for loop with ifelse statement in r?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following code, which produces what I want, but I'm almost certain that it can be written better (also it takes a long time to execute). Any suggestions for how I can clean it up?

The basic idea is that I want a table that includes the "highest" letter (A, B or C) in the variable `var3` for each unique combination of `var1` og `var2`

```
var1 <- c(rep.int(1:3,3))
var2 <- c(sample(letters[1:3],
                 NROW(var1),
                 replace = TRUE))
var3 <- c(sample(LETTERS[1:3],
                 NROW(var1),
                 replace = TRUE))
df <- data.frame(var1,
                 var2,
                 var3)
x <- capture.output(for (i in unique(df$var1)) {
  for (j in unique(df$var2)) {
    ifelse(
      "A" %in% subset(df,
                      df$var1 == i &
                        df$var2 == j,
                      select = c(var3))[,1]
      ,print("A"),
      ifelse(
        "B" %in% subset(df,
                        df$var1 == i &
                          df$var2 == j,
                        select = c(var3))[,1],
        print("B"),
        ifelse(
          "C" %in% subset(df,
                          df$var1 == i &
                            df$var2 == j,
                          select = c(var3))[,1],
          print("C"),0
        )
      )
    )
  }
})
as.data.frame(cbind(x,unique(paste(df$var1,df$var2))))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "highest"?

Comment: A>B>C, i.e. if A is present, then I want A, if B then B etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'var1', and 'var2', we convert the 'var3' to `factor` with `levels` specified, get the index of minimum value (`which.min`) and subset the dataset (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(factor(var3, 
            levels=LETTERS[1:3]))] ,.(var1, var2)]
```

Or after grouping, we `order` by 'var3' converted to `factor` and get the 1st observation of the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`).

```
setDT(df)[order(factor(var3, levels=LETTERS[1:3])), 
                 head(.SD, 1L), .(var1, var2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with `dplyr`, like here:

```
library("dplyr")

df %>% 
    group_by(var1, var2) %>% 
    summarise(maksymalna=max(as.character(var3)))
```

It gives different output than yours (probably sth is wrong in your function), but I think it's correct. Could you check?

Comment: Didn't get me the right result as I sometimes would have A in combination that didn't get returned correctly, but thanks for the suggestion!